# Python 3 interacting with subprocess via UDP on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, camera, subprocess, python-multithreading

I want to warm up raspistill via a subprocess call triggered via UDP and then at a desired time trigger image capture via a separate UDP command:

`UDP_listener()` as thread 1:

```
if data == "PRIME":
            print("Priming...")
            if (isTakingImage == False):
                t = threading.Thread(target= prime_camera)  
                t.start()
                t.join()
if data == "IMAGE":
      print("taking image")
      t2 = threading.Thread(target = take_image)
      t2.start()
      t2.join()
```

`prime_camera()` as thread 2

```
cmd = 'raspistill -t 0 -o test.jpg -s
p1 = Popen(shlex.split(cmd))
```

How can I pass further communication to successfully trigger:

```
take_image():
     cmd = "pkill -USR1 raspistill"
     p2 = Popen(shlex.split(cmd))
```

Currently, no input is being received / ack being sent back from the Raspberry while `prime_camera()` is running.

Is my approach incorrect? What am I missing?

Thanks for your time
Steve

Answer (score 0):

When you start your thread to prime the camera, you do:

```
t = threading.Thread(target= prime_camera)  
t.start()
t.join()
```

which means you start a new thread, **and then hang** on the `t.join()` - waiting till it exits, so you have achieved nothing in parallel. You need to leave the thread running so it is ready to respond to your subsequent signal, then join it after you have finished taking pictures.

So, remove the `t.join()` and run it later when the `raspistill` process has finished.

Comment: Sorry for the late comeback. Thanks!